# Dijkstra's Algorithm Implementation using classes

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I'm trying to solve a problem on HackerRank and I've tried solving it and i found it giving distances like -2149088 although is there a problem with my logic  most importantly inside the while loop .can anyone point out my mistakes im a noob :) Thanks. Link to the problem statement HackerRank : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dijkstrashortreach

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.math.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int cases = in.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i<cases; i++){
        int N = in.nextInt();
        int M = in.nextInt();
        int adj[][] = new int[N+1][N+1];

        Node nodes[] = new Node[N+1];

        for(int k=1; k<=N; k++)
           nodes[k] = new Node(k);    


        for(int j=0; j<=N; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<=N; k++)
                adj[j][k] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


        for(int j=0; j<M; j++){

            int A = in.nextInt();
            int B = in.nextInt();
            int W = in.nextInt();

            adj[A][B] = Math.min(W,adj[A][B]);
            adj[B][A] = Math.min(W,adj[A][B]);
        }

        int S = in.nextInt();

        nodes[S].dist = 0;
        PriorityQueue<Node> que = new  PriorityQueue<Node>();

        for(int k=1; k<=N; k++)
            que.add(nodes[k]);


        while(!que.isEmpty()){
            Node q = que.poll();
            int id = q.ID;

            for(int j=1; j<=N; j++){
                if(adj[id][j] != Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                     System.out.println(""+q.dist);
                    if(nodes[j].dist>q.dist+adj[id][j]){
                      nodes[j].dist = q.dist+adj[id][j];

                    } 
                }
            }
        }

        for(int j=1; j<=N; j++){
            if(nodes[j].dist==Integer.MAX_VALUE){System.out.println("-1");}
            else if(nodes[j].dist!=0) {System.out.print(nodes[j].dist+" ");}
        }
    }

}

}

class Node implements Comparable<Node>{

    public int dist;
    public int ID;

    public Node(int getID){
        this.ID = getID;
        dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }    


    @Override
    public int compareTo (Node node) {
        return Integer.valueOf(this.dist).compareTo(node.dist);
    }   
}
```

Comment: "don't know what's wrong with my code" is too vague. You should try to focus your problem instead of dumping code and  write "it doesn't work"....

Comment: Got it ! The thing is i forgot about nodes that are not attached to the graph. and so i had to set the dist which was set to infinity to 0 for "q" in the code. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your dist to Integer.MAX_VALUE and then check it here:

```
                    if(nodes[j].dist>q.dist+adj[id][j]){
                      nodes[j].dist = q.dist+adj[id][j];

                    }
```

Then nodes[j].dist is always bigger than q.dist+adj[id][j], because MAX_VALUE + adj[id][j] < 0. You have there a integer overflow and assign the overflowed value to nodes[j].dist.

I hope it helps.